# PHP: prevent from overflow the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have tiny url service , the sending data to the server is working simply with ajax function which send data to certain page and insert the data to the database.

I just have played a little bit with firebug and i found out that i can loop the ajax function thousands times in a second and it's floating my database.. which i just did..

session and cookies could not work here from obvious reason..

```
how can i prevent this?
```

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375501/how-do-i-throttle-my-sites-api-users

Comment: Are you looking for a safeguard against accidental misuse, "let me try this"-attacks or malicious "script kiddies"?

Answer (score 1):

A very easy way to fix this issue that works really well and prevents DDOS attacks is to use bulk inserts on a post processing function.  For your tinyurl have the call save all the data that is being entered as a concatenated file on the filesystem in a flat text file for instance (CSV) works well for this.

Then run a cron job every 1 ~ 5 minutes that reads the text file and does a *bulk* insert to mysql.  The key here is doing bulk inserts.  It's much more efficient to do 1 bulk insert than 100,000,000 single queries.

To give you an idea I deal with massive data inserts on a daily basis, where we get roughly 1 million insert requests per minute.  Doing 1 mil inserts as single queries will take on our *huge* db server about 15 minutes.  Doing them as a bulk insert takes about 18 seconds.  It's staggering how much faster bulk inserts are and you also only consume 1 connection on your mysql box.

Bulk inserts are very similar to a regular insert the only difference in the query is in the VALUES part.  Where you would normally have VALUES=('abc','123','abc') for instance you would now have... VALUES=(('abc','123','abcd'),('cde','456','dsw');

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to prevent is a DOS (Denial of Service) attack.  There is a lot of information out on the web on how to prevent this.  For a very simple service solution, you can limit the interaction with your database to require a pause between requests.

You can use sessions to help prevent this.

Flow:

1. User views page - create session
2. User uses service based via ajax
3. On ajax request - check if session contains "last_run" timestamp.
4. If it does not exist, allow the query, add "last_run"
5. If it does exist and the timestamp is older than your timeout (say, 1 second), allow the query, update "last_run".
6. If it does exist and the timestamp is not older than your timeout, don't allow the query.

Comment: This might be a protection against accidental misuse and refresh-refresh-refresh "attacks". It does not hinder someone to throw the session cookie away and make a new request.

Comment: Correct, this is only a simple solution.  If more is necessary, we'd need a lot more information about the particular setup, what he's actually trying to prevent, number of transactions, if hardware solutions are feasible, etc.