# Laravel reset password spam

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I'm using Laravel DEFAULT password reset, and it works perfectly, but there is one little problem, I can request 'password reset' every single minute, and I don't like it, so my question is how to reduce that request time like, I wanna be able to make 2 request every 5m.

/ForgotPasswordController.php

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        if (preg_match('/en/',url()->previous())){
            App::setLocale('en');
        }else{
            App::setLocale('ru');
        }

        $this->middleware('guest');

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ThrottleRequests middleware that Laravel provides by default, either by defining it in the controller constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (preg_match('/en/', url()->previous())) {
        App::setLocale('en');
    } else {
        App::setLocale('ru');
    }

    $this->middleware('throttle:2,5');
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

...or by tacking it onto the route definition.

```
Route::post('/password/reset', 'ForgotPasswordController@yourFunction')
    ->middleware('throttle:2,5');
```

Additional information on the parameters: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-and-api-rate-limiting/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would use a time comparison or leaky bucket which simply records the last request. The time for a password reset should be logged in the backend and then conditionals can be used to ensure that no two resets can be done in under 5 minutes. View these examples:

- [Time Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138984/a-portable-way-of-providing-an-ip-based-cooldown-period)
- [Leaky Bucket Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375501/how-do-i-throttle-my-sites-api-users)

Comment: CloudFlare's [Sliding Window](https://blog.cloudflare.com/counting-things-a-lot-of-different-things/) is quite nice and only requires storing 2 values and some simple math.