# Php api to handle only 5 request per user

Tags: php

say I have a php api like,

`api.example.com/request.php?apikey=example123`.

In order not to speed up the processes on my hosting site, I just want the user to have 5 consecutive API calls that say they run on multiple tabs. And if they open the Sixth tab for example they get the request blocked. How is this possible? Or is it possible?

Any help or suggestion ?

Comment: can you show us your best try to achieve this. and one more thing API opening in multiple tabs by code?

Comment: You can just maintain daily count of API hit of each user in a db. When count reaches 5, stop serving the page after that

Comment: @PiNaKa30 yes that is also possible but what if the api call was too long and they suddenly closed and that is counted on the sql table, how do I detect the user if they didnt wait for the api to load

Comment: So call your count API in the onload method of page from Javascript. That way you surely know that the page was loaded completely before user closed it

Comment: @PiNaKa30 or if the php has status code of 200, how do I check that if(status == 200)

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375501/how-do-i-throttle-my-sites-api-users?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375501/how-do-i-throttle-my-sites-api-users?rq=1)